# Is it possible to change the /health endpoint in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring-boot-web application and I am using actuator to check status of my application. Whenever I do /health I am able to check the status of my application. My doubt is, is it possible to change the /health endpoint to something like /ABC/health(I need to add context to /health). Is it possible or do I need to have a controller for this and need to handle it.

Comment: Anybody need more info can refer this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) . Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a built-in property to expose all Actuator endpoints under different path. Just set it in your **application.properties** file:

```
management.context-path=/ABC
```

The health will be than available under `/ABC/health`.